# django circleci unit testing issues

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, circleci

every time I run manage.py test I get about 40 errors like this:

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/home/james/alzheimers/webportal/fixtures/natt_search_db.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=7): UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.app_label, django_content_type.model
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: no.  just "model": "contenttypes.contenttype"

Comment: Could you please get in touch with us via the in-app help dialog or an email to sayhi(at)circleci(dot)com? Thanks!